# Error in syntax of stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE  PROCEDURE final_arrest ()
AS 
cursor c_final_arrest is 
select greatest(Week 1,Week 2)as a ,
greatest(Week 1,Week 3) as b ,
greatest(Week 2,Week 3) as c
from arrest
for update;
c_a number;
c_b number;
c_c number;
c_sum number;
c_avg number;
begin
open c_final_arrest;
loop
fetch c_final_arrest into c_a,c_b,c_c;
exit when c_final_arrest % notfound;
if(c_a != c_b)then
c_sum := c_a + c_b;
else
c_sum := c_a + c_c;
end if;
c_avg := c_sum/2;
update arrest set Avg=c_avg
where current of c_final_arrest;
end loop;
close c_final_arrest;
end //
DELIMITER ;
```

Can anyone help me out with this..!! I am not able to create this procedure in mysql....Keep getting the error

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS

cursor c_final_arrest is
select greatest(Week 1,Week 2)as a ,
greatest(W' at line 2

I am not sure what to do...Help

If anyone can give an alternative code it would be nice...!!!

Comment: put ` symbol on fields

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: what this? "AS 
cursor c_final_arrest is"
I don't think it is supposed to be there

Comment: The first error is a missing `BEGIN`; later you are missing `DECLARE`.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I wrote stored procedures - but I would look at the following:

1) Look carefully at spacing - i.e. Change "greatest(Week 1,Week 2)as" to "greatest(Week 1, Week 2) as"

2) "a" could be reserved - I would use more descriptive column names
3) Column names "Week n" contain a space. You might need quotes "" or brackets [] around the column name such as "greatest([Week 1], [Week 2]) as"

Comment: True - that is where the compiler first determines there is an issue. For me, this says that the issue is somewhere on that line - but not necessary where the compiler noticed the problem.